# Enterprise library - Email Trace Listener is not working though i provided everything?

Tags: enterprise-library

i have email event listner like, but the emails are not sending, please help me on this

and my exception handling code is

Comment: Please provide some code, web.config settings?

Answer (score 1):

First check that you can send emails via your configured email server from the installation computer, Microsoft KB153119 will tell you how to do this.

Second check it is the email listener that is failing. Remove all but the email listener and try again. It removing the Event log listener helps then the application might not have sufficient rights to create the event log source (this should be done by the installer).

Third check the exception that would trigger an email is being raised, either step through code or swap the email listener to a text file listener.

Finally, as Ashwani says, provide a little of your code and config for us to look at.